# How to set signature in keras.models.save_ model

Tags: tensorflow

## My environment

tf:2.3
system:ubuntu 18

## My question

I updated from tf14 to tf2.3. The model I used is a model of keras type. After viewing the official document, adding signature failed

## My main code

```
model = VGG16(weights = weights_dir)
...
keras.models.save_model(model, model_dir_saved_model)
```

This function has the input of signature, but I don't know how to organize it

## Here's my try

```
def saveKerasModelAsProtobuf(model, outputPath):
    inputs = {'image': utils.build_tensor_info(model.input)}
    outputs = {'scores': utils.build_tensor_info(model.output)}

    signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs, outputs, 'name')

    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(outputPath)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess=keras.backend.get_session(),
        tags=['serving_default'],
        signature_def_map={'serving_default': signature})
    builder.save()
```

So, what's the right way to keep it

Answer (score 0):

The serving signatures are for [TensorFlow **Serving**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) and [saved_model_cli](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#details_of_the_savedmodel_command_line_interface), are you using any of these?

If not, you don't have to worry about setting a signature, the model will be saved/ loaded fine without them. Can you explain why you need them?

> Key Point: Unless you need to export your model to an environment other than TensorFlow 2.x with Python, you probably don't need to export signatures explicitly. If you're looking for a way of enforcing an input signature for a specific function, see the input_signature argument to tf.function. [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#specifying_signatures_during_export)